# What was the first question on SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

Can someone send me a link to the first question on SO?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/questions/4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4)  (old & alive)

Comment: @iammilind not in 2k18 :P

Answer (score 76):

It was [Where, oh where, did the Joel Data go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/where-oh-where-did-the-joel-data-go)

For people with less than 10k rep:

[image: First SO question]

([Click for full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brLpH.png))

Comment: Stephan: Although as Kyle says, the post is locked, people with >10k rep can only vote to undelete questions now, answers must be un-deleted by their owners or a moderator

Comment: So this is the first. What about the second and third?

Comment: @puretppc The second question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/ mentioned below (ID 2 and 3 were answers to the Joel-data question). The third question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8/tool-for-converting-visual-j-code-to-c

Comment: How could a first answer's user get a reputation of 1.3k+?

Comment: @KyleAbrahamJr -- like anybody else: they earn rep over time.  Just because they answered the question when they did doesn't mean their rep at that time was snapshotted and glued to the answer.  The screenshot above was captured when their rep was 1.3K.

Answer (score 41):

First? Dunno. The second was "When setting a form’s opacity should I use a decimal or double?":

[While applying opacity to a form should we use a decimal or double value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4)

Comment: This is actually the second question ever; and the first real one.

Comment: This is down voted because it's the second question, not the fourth. It has the id of 4 is because: 1 - the first question, 2 - the first answer, 3 - the second answer, 4 - the second question. If you have enough rep you can still access them.

Comment: @Jonathan - so it sounds like this was the first real question. That's what I wanted to know once I saw the real first question (the real first was kind of a dud).

Comment: This is by an official test account.

Answer (score 26):

There is no link, but [the official tweet from StackOverflow](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/624575358306795522) revealed the REAL answer:

> well, technically the first question was @codinghorror asking "where are my pants?" but it was deleted at the database level

Answer (score 21):

The first real question from a *non-test account* is:

[Percentage width child element in absolutely positioned parent on Internet Explorer 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6/why-doesnt-the-percentage-width-child-in-absolutely-positioned-parent-work-in-i)

Answer (score 16):

The first question that wasn't deleted was this one:

[While applying opacity to a form should we use a decimal or double value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/)

**Update**
Questions and Responses in Stack Overflow all share the same ID Generator (they are likely in the same table?), and that explains why QuestionIDs aren't incremental at all.

Comment: The question numbers include answers as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I remember Jeff mentioning on a podcast that they share the id number generator across multiple columns.

Comment: If you check out the user for the linked question (http://stackoverflow.com/users/8/eggs-mclaren) you'll see that it's a dummy account used by Jeff Atwood and that this is the only question the user ever asked. This was clearly a test question. It's likely that earlier questions (0-3) were also test questions that were deleted for one reason or another.

Comment: 1 was a question, I think the others were answers to that question.

Comment: looks like it has been deleted now