# Why does questions/20 redirect to questions/8/#20?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

While trying to find the first alive question on SO, I discovered something strange.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20

will redirect to

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8/are-there-any-conversion-tools-for-porting-visual-j-code-to-c/20#20

Why is this?

Comment: btw, this seems to be the first SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/

Comment: The [first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1) is only visible if you have 10k. @ear

Comment: @The Cat: That makes me wonder if SO got off to a roaring start by closing its very first question as 'not a real question.'

Comment: @The Cat. How about a screenshot for us that are under 10k? :)

Comment: Found it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3991/what-was-the-first-question-on-so

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions and answers are both stored in the same database table. [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump).

ID #20 is the ID of an *answer*, which is inside a question with ID #8.

The database design goes against the RESTful URL design of /questions/x (since not all posts are questions), so if x is an answer, the devs decided to redirect there instead of bombing it with a 404. You'll notice that when you edit a post, the url is /posts/x/edit regardless of whether it's a question or answer.

Comment: You can see this clearly through the URLs alone with /posts/ID/revisions.