# What approach should I take to find the oldest question on a stack exchange site?

Tags: support, sorting

How do I find the oldest questions (such as the first asked question by anyone) on a stack exchange site.

Was having a look through a users profile on Ask Different and had the idea to see who asked the first question there.

Is there a hack?

**Edit:**
Fair point directing me to the last page on the questions page. Many questions are added per second on SO so getting the last one on the last page is fiddly and I figured there might be another way. The best I can get with my access on SO, telling by a pretty URL, is question 4 for C#on setting form opacity: [While applying opacity to a form should we use a decimal or double value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4/977087)

As the answers pointed out I don't have the points to see all answers such as Joel Spolsky's [data one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/where-oh-where-did-the-joel-data-go).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/where-oh-where-did-the-joel-data-go)(10k only) is the first question ever asked.

Comment: The trick is to know that questions are numbered sequentially. So if you take the URL to any question, then change the number to 1, 2, 3, etc. you'll see the first, second, third, etc. question that was asked.

Comment: @Cody yep, only downside is we can't get the *newest* question this way. :)

Comment: @Crowie: You can see the answers to the first question with a little hack: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2/edit/ <- first answer, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3/edit/ <- 2nd answer, ... But that does not work for the question itself since it is locked.

Comment: The pretty URL numbering is different on Ask Different... no pun intended

Comment: Well, the difference on Ask Different is that the questions at the very end of the list (the oldest ones by *date*) were not asked directly on that site. They were migrated from someplace else, like Stack Overflow. That would be true on all sites, a possible limitation of the trick I mentioned. It depends on what you're interested in.

Comment: These questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/convert-decimal-to-double and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/where-oh-where-did-the-joel-data-go are unfortunately deleted by now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way if you're too lazy to go each site is by using the Data Explorer.

[Here is a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/126944/find-first-undeleted-question-on-a-site) that will give back the first (undeleted) question on any site, you can switch sites as much as you want:

> [image]

Comment: Although it's a bit complicated, I figure this is the best way to see the oldest and does provide it generally for any site regardless of what level of access I have

Answer (score 2):

Go the the *newest* questions tab and click on the last page at the bottom.

There you find the first questions ever asked on a site (starting from the 2nd question ever).

The very first question is deleted though. 10k+ users can view it.
It is [Where, oh where, did the Joel Data go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/where-oh-where-did-the-joel-data-go)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4139/133343

Comment: This isn't a good strategy on some sites. On [webapps.se], before the 60-day limit for migrations was implemented, a _tonne_ of questions were migrated over from [su]. So, even though the site opened in June, 2010, and the [first question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1/354) has an appropriate date, the questions-sorted-by-new strategy would have you think that [a question from about a year before the site existed](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/13413/354) was the first question.