# Is there any way to find the first ever question posted on an SE site?

Tags: support, search

Sometimes I like to see old questions, as it shows you how much the site evolved over the years. Some old questions are really simple, showing no research and at times even obvious. The answers are also very simple but reasonable too. Gradually, SE sites have become much more sophisticated and elaborate, and that tells me something not only about the site itself, but also about internet behaviour.

I find this fascinating and usually I just click on `Questions` and then click on the last page number at the bottom. Does that take me to the first questions ever to be asked on that particular site, or have old questions been deleted? Is there a way to search questions by year? Also, how can I find out the date when a certain SE site was created?

***Edit:*** Please note that I am looking for ***a way to find these questions myself***, I am not asking for links that will take me directly there. Also, while there is a way to get to the first question, I am looking for a way to find the questions that succeeded ***in a chronological order***, as a list. I just wish there was a simpler way, that's all. So no, the duplicates indicated do not answer my question. Plus, they are all closed!

Comment: @ARogueAnt. 61080 was [migrated](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/61080/revisions). Question 1 was the first question posted to ELU, but 61080 is the oldest question on the site

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Yes EL&U is one of the sites I am interested in. When I press on Questions it tells me there are "122,195 questions"... does that mean it includes migrated questions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What approach should I take to find the oldest question on a stack exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191404/what-approach-should-i-take-to-find-the-oldest-question-on-a-stack-exchange-site)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort the search results?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217896/how-can-i-sort-the-search-results), similarly (following the answer's link) you can use "created:" to find the earliest posts.

Comment: I think bobble's dupe target is a much better fit than the search results one.

Comment: @zcoop98 While I have accepted Rob's dupe, I think rene's and Dudec's answers are unique and provide an approach that the indicated duplicates have not. So I am happy this page brings new information, although the question is closed as a duplicate. Bobble's dupe gave me links, but not the way to get to them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most reliable way is using this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1448003) under the assumption the lowest id in the PostsWithDeleted table is the first post for that site.

```sql
select *
from (select top 1
        id
     , 'first on id' [category]
     ,  concat('site://q/',id, '|', coalesce(title, 'deleted')) [Q Link]
     , creationdate
     , score
     , tags
from postswithdeleted
order by id asc
) data
union
select *
from (
select top 1
        id
     , 'first non-deleted Q on id' [category]
     ,  concat('site://q/',id, '|', coalesce(title, 'deleted')) [Q Link]
     , creationdate
     , score
     , tags
from postswithdeleted
where deletiondate is null
and posttypeid = 1
order by id asc
) data2
union
select *
from (
select top 1
        id
     , 'first on creationdate' [category]
     ,  concat('site://q/',id, '|', coalesce(title, 'deleted')) [Q Link]
     , creationdate
     , score
     , tags
from postswithdeleted
order by creationdate asc
) data3
union
select *
from (
select top 1
        id
     , 'first non-deleted Q on date' [category]
     ,  concat('site://q/',id, '|', coalesce(title, 'deleted')) [Q Link]
     , creationdate
     , score
     , tags
from postswithdeleted
where deletiondate is null
and posttypeid = 1
order by creationdate asc
) data4
```

This might give wrong / a-typical timeline issues if a site was created by merging / feeding from another site. The MSO - MSE split springs to mind but I recall Audio.se and Video.se also got merged into AVP.se so these might give weird first posts, as in: not correct based on creationdate.

Here is the result for Meta Stack Overflow:

[image]

Notice you can run the query yourself and switch to a different site by  typing the site name in the text box.

Here is an instructional screencast how to switch between sites and then run the query:

[image]

Comment: How do you get to the SEDE query of a particular site? I am really illiterate in this field. maybe I should have asked this question on that particular site's meta? EL&U.

Comment: @fev which site do you need?

Comment: English Language and Usage and English Learners SE for a start.

Comment: @fev I've added a screencast to my answer on how to switch between sites for a specific query but here are the direct links for [ell](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/1448003) and [elu](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/1448003).

Answer (score 6):

Posts have sequential ids, so the first question will be at `<site>.stackexchange.com/questions/1` for any given `<site>`. For example, the first question here is [Should meta.stackoverflow.com replace uservoice.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1) (or, as a raw URL, `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1`).

Note that the ids are for sequential *posts*, not sequential questions. [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3) points to the third post (the first answer), not the third question.

Additionally, migrated questions may mean that the oldest question on a site is not the first question posted to that site. For example, on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/), the first question posted was [When do I use "can" or "could"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1) (id 1), but the oldest post is [The plural of "index"–"indexes" or "indices"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/61080) (id 61080) as it was migrated from Stack Overflow

Comment: The raw URL seems to work, but not the sequential id on the SE site I am using. How can I find the second and the third questions, etc? Only through these URLs?

Comment: @fev The sequential id is for *posts*, not only *questions*. [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3) will point to the third post on the MSE, which is the first answer.

Comment: That's a rather complicated way to go about it, but at least that's a start.